# Jekyll search with Lunr JS, not working

Tags: json, search, jekyll, lunrjs

I'm trying to implement search on my Jekyll site using Lunar JS  with this plugin. https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search

I'm following the instructions in the readme but to a beginner they are not so clear.

I've followed everything up to step 5, ie added all the scripts to my template, and created a search box and container for my search results on the page I want to have search functionality.

However, step 6 says: "Create a Mustache template to display the search results." Where do I need to put this code? In a separate file? Or on the same page as I have my search box?

And step 7 requires me to add:

```
`indexUrl: '/search.json',  // URL of the `search.json` index data for your site`
```

Can somebody explain what this means? I know lunrjs is supposed to create a json file with all my blog data, but I can't find this json file anywhere. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the json and nokogiri ruby gems installed. Type:

```
gem install json
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to find a workaround as plugins are not supported by github pages, I am using lunr with jekyll by following the process from [this page](http://jekyll.tips/jekyll-casts/jekyll-search-using-lunr-js/). You can of course then modify this to get the data from a json file that you'll create with liquid code.